# Is my approach correct to check the sufficiency of the static

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation, sufficient-statistics

Let we have $n$ random variables from Poisson distribution with parameters $\lambda$. It is required to check the sufficiency of the following estimators

a). $(X_1,\sum_{i=2}^{n}X_i)$
b). $(X_1,\bar{X})$

**My approach**

The joint distribution function of the samples is:

$f(X|\theta)=\frac{e^{-n\lambda 
}\lambda^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}}{\prod X_i}$

For the first option, we can write the likelihood as:

$f(X|\theta)=\frac{e^{-n\lambda 
}\lambda^{X_1+\sum_{i=2}^{n} X_i}}{\prod X_i}$

The above likelihood equation can be expressed as the function of $h(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and $g((x_1,\sum_{i=2}^{n}),\lambda)$. Hence, the first one is sufficient. But for the second one, i am not sure how can i express the second Statistic in the above form. I know it will be sufficient but not sure how to express it in terms of factorization theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can write $$ \sum_{k=1}^n X_k = n\bar X.$$ The fact that you don't even need $X_1$ is irrelevant: if $\bar X$ is sufficient, then $(\bar X,X_1)$ certainly is.

Comment: Could please elaborate and explain why $X_1$ is irrelevant? $\bar X$ is 1D and $(\bar{X} ,X_1)$ is 2D?

Comment: @Daman I didn't say $X_1$ is irrelevant. I said the fact that you don't need $X_1$ in (b) is irrelevant. What I meant by "you don't even need $X_1$" was that $\bar X$ is already sufficient by itself.

Comment: Since $X_1$ is not Sufficient how come $( \bar{X},X_{1})$ is sufficient? Can I say among $X_1$ and $\bar{X}$ ,$\bar{X}$ is sufficient therefor they are jointly sufficient ?

Comment: @Daman Yes, it's because $\bar X$ *is* sufficient.

Comment: Can I write it like this $(\bar {X} ,X_2,X_3,X_4+X_6)$ and it would still be sufficient ?

Comment: @Daman Yes. Add the distance from earth to the moon to the end of the list and it's still sufficient, since $\bar X$ is.

Comment: Since $\sum_{i=2}^{n}X_i$ is sufficient how come  $(X_1,\sum_{i=2}^{n}X_i)$ is sufficient if I follow same path as above intuitively and not writing joint PDF.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118100/discussion-between-daman-and-spaceisdarkgreen).

Comment: OP says its sufficient .

Comment: @Daman No, OP says $(X_1,\sum_{i=2}^\infty X_i)$ is sufficient, which it is. Just $\sum_{i=2}^\infty X_i$ alone is not. (Somehow I accidentally deleted my comment above saying $\sum_{i=2}^\infty X_i$ is not sufficient, to which you were responding.)

Comment: Yes, that's what am I saying$ (X_1,\sum_{i=2}^\infty X_i) $is sufficient but how do I figure it out without joint pdf? Can I say that sum of $X_1$ and $ \sum_{i=2}^\infty X_i$ makes it whole sample space thus sufficient?

Comment: @Daman Yes, if the sum (or any function) of two statistics is sufficient, then the two statistics are jointly sufficient.

Comment: @Daman Why would you need the joint pdf of the two statistics? (If that's what you mean.) You just need the joint pdf of all the $X_i,$ and then verify via the factorization theorem (or some other way) that $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is sufficient.

Comment: Oh yes indeed thanks